# Existing consumer group does not receive messages anymore

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are chasing a strange behavior for a while now - asking your help because we ran out of ideas. Maybe someone has a few good ideas/pointers?

Components we use:

- We are using Kafka 2.2.1 iirc cluster - 3 nodes setup
- Topics having 6 partitions
- We are working in Java and using org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka 2.6.3 (also tested with latest 2.7.7 - did not help)

**The problem:**
In our use case we have a few topics where we do not have a continuous consumer, but we just fire one (only one at a time! - consuming all partitions) up periodically / on demand. And we use MANUAL AckMode because sometimes we just want to count the messages and not really process them.
The consumer is created from Java code programmatically - done by this snippet:

```
@Autowired
KafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory;

MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = kafkaListenerContainerFactory.createContainer(topicName);
listenerContainer.setupMessageListener(this);   // our class implements AcknowledgingMessageListener<Object, String>
listenerContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("MyService");
listenerContainer.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
listenerContainer.start();

... we wait until no more inbound messages (for X seconds, timeout fashion)

listenerContainer.stop();
```

The strange thing is that although everything works as expected,
sometimes / somehow we get into a "state" we do not receive any messages anymore when we start the consumer. However, we do know for sure there are messages as our "MyService" consumer group there has an offset lag (we have Prometheus+Grafana metrics from Kafka for that so we see).

What makes the above even more weird:

- This "state" can self-heal after a while without doing anything, so everything returns to normal. However, how long this state exists varies a lot! Sometimes just 1-2 hours other times might take days (and sometimes weeks).
- We have DEV, STAGE, PROD environment - PROD is more powerful regarding Kafka side. The above weird behavior we experience in DEV and STAGE, but PROD not (just happened once during 6 months, for 2 hours then gone).

What we can also add to the above:

- Retention period does not play role here. This state can happen even with just a few hours old messages on the topics.
- When this weird state happens restarting the JVM (so the Java app) does not help.
- We can break out from this state with a small trick: when the consumer is active, we send a message to the topic. Then suddenly Kafka somehow recovers from this state and suddenly starts to send all the messages not processed by the "MyService" consumer group

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like nothing to do with Spring, but just unusual behavior of regular Apache Kafka consumer... Perhaps better to commit offsets anyway?

Comment: Yeah we also think so (nothing to do to Spring). This might be unusual however still valid use case and should work due to specification. I can not recall exactly but I remember I was reading articles explicitly saying "Kafka could be used as perfect temporary storage" and this is exactly what we are shooting for here. Not even mentioning that it is also possible a normally constantly running service (consumer) just goes down on Friday evening and only restored Monday morning by colleagues it is the same effect.

Comment: The default value for auto.offset.reset is latest. It seems the consumer sees all the messages as commited in the topics sometimes. Is enable.auto.commit false? Default value is true. Which is auto.commit.interval.ms? It defaults to 5 seconds.

Comment: @Saxon: Thanks but I'm not sure how these settings like enable.auto.commit and others come into the picture - as everything is done from code purely here... My understanding is that those properties are affecting auto-instrumented consumers only (like `@KafkaListener` annotated methods) no?

Comment: Take a thread dump the next time it happens - most of the time, the problem is the consumer thread is "stuck" somewhere in the listener code - also DEBUG logging will help since the number or records received from each poll are logged.

Comment: Spring kafka listener consumer properties: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerProperties.html You can set consumer properties at the consumer factory level as well.

Comment: @GaryRussell if that would be the case then App (JVM) restart would help no? But it does not... Once we get into this state it does not matter if I restart the App state remains.
Maybe the Kafka client sends (during connecting) something wrong to the Kafka broker...? One more info: we see by logging out listenerContainer.getAssignedPartitions() that actually all partitions are assigned to us. Still nothing comes...

Comment: That is odd, indeed; if it weren't for the "self healing" you describe, I would say @Saxon 's comment about `auto.offset.reset` was the case - if the consumer is down for a week (by default) the offsets are expired and you will re-start at the end of the topic; I don's see how it can self-heal from that. Try DEBUG logging and look at the committed offsets using the `kafka-consumer-groups` CLT to `--describe` the group(s).